# How to precompute array of values?

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to pre-compute an array of values based on templates?  In the following example I would like the 'powers_of_2' array to have 256 values computed at compile-time if that is possible without having to type all of the values.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <int X, char Y>
struct power {
   enum { value = X * power<X,Y-1>::value };
};

template <int X>
struct power<X,1> {
   enum { value = X };
};

template <int X>
struct power<X,0> {
   enum { value = 1 };
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   int powers_of_2[] = { power<2,0>::value, power<2,1>::value, ..., power<2,255>::value };
   cout << powers_of_2[1] << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually now that I look at your question again (other than the overflow problem) it looks like you already have the answer. ???

Answer (score 4):

Unless you plan on using a big integer package you will overflow the integer type at 2^32 (or 2^64, depending), but to answer your real question look at this wikipedia article on [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming).

Comment: I modified my question so Y is now of type char instead of int.

Comment: If Y is not an unsigned char, which it looks like it isn't then your range for Y is -128 to 127. Even if Y is unsigned the range is only from 0 to 255 (so you are missing 256). Even so X is still an integer and it will overflow at 2^32 or 2^64 depending on the machine and compiler.

Comment: Template metaprogramming is not sufficient for such task. Even if macros do not support recursion, they are the only viable way to implement statement repetition.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what a macro is useful for...

Answer (score 1):

Holding the value 2^255 would require 32 bytes.  This cannot be held in an int; you'd need a char array

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE32[32];
BYTE32 powers_of_2[256] =
{
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,64},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,128},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0},
// :
// :
  {32,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {64,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do in situations like that is write a small program that generates and writes to a file the array initialization in C++ source and then #include that file. This technique is simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily write a small script to prepopulate the array for you using your preferred scripting language. Depending on the compiler and preprocessor you use, you should also be able to do it as a macro.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lokkju. It is not possible to initialize the array by only means of template metaprogramming and macros in this case are very useful. Even Boost libraries make use of macros to implement repetitive statements.

Examples of useful macros are available here: http://awgn.antifork.org/codes++/macro_template.h